# Why `tf.nn.nce_loss` in tensorflow cannot run on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

The code `tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py` has a comment `# Ops and variables pinned to the CPU because of missing GPU implementation`. I have also found that the operation `tf.nn.nce_loss` cannot be implemented by GPU. So why tf.nn.nce_loss cannot run on GPU?

I have used `log_device_placement` to see the `MUST BE CPU` Ops. Here is the result:

```
nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler: (LogUniformCandidateSampler)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/ComputeAccidentalHits: (ComputeAccidentalHits)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/SparseToDense: (SparseToDense)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] nce_loss/concat: (ConcatV2)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

However, I still don't know which special Ops cause this problem. Is there any special Ops that cannot be implemented by GPU? Or is this due to the lack of implementation by tensorflow itself?

Comment: according to this you can use GPU if you have GPU
https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/2017/lectures/notes_04.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this example using gpu accelerator as well.
See tensorflow supported devices https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#supported_devices
You have to add following line of code

```py
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
```

and remove `#with tf.device('/cpu:0'):`

Basically replace cpu with gpu on this line:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bd965956535b1026a0769d04c3f6419d020f5f9c/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py#L189

Hope this helps.